# PlayFramework: Templates and Razor Syntax

Tags: scala, razor, playframework

Here below is a template for generating a HTML email... and I want to put the current time in the body according to the user's timezone:

```
@(user: models.auth.User)(implicit request: RequestHeader, lang: Lang)

@import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeZone}
@import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat

...

@user.timeZone.map { tz =>
  var timeZone = DateTimeZone.forId(tz)
  val formatter = DateTimeFormat.mediumDateTime.withZone(timeZone)
  val currentTime = formatter.print(DateTime.now)
  <p>@Messages("email.timestamp", currentTime)</p>
}
<p>@Messages("email.salutation")</p>
```

The code above does not compile because the compiler doesn't find `currentTime` when invoking `@Messages`.

What's the syntax to pass `currentTime` to `@Messsages`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

@defining({
// code computing time
   }) { currentTime =>

@currenTime

}